# Codeigniter Global data to be used on controllers

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

So a brief intro, I'm trying to make a web app for posting stories and viewing stories.

I divided my controller into two, story controller and user controller. Any function i write that involves the story part of my project i write it inside story controller and any user function i have is in user controller.

For example:

> public function add_story(){} is in story controller.
>
> public function register(){} is in user controller.

Also in loading my views i separated them into templates and pages.

Inside templates are the header/navbar/footer. The pages are all  contents of my html so only the pages differ.

```
$this->load->view('template/header');
$this->load->view('template/navbar');
$this->load->view('pages/page_name');
$this->load->view('template/footer');
```

Now my question is in the navbar. I want to add a notification function. I already have it in my head i just need to implement it but i'm indecisive as to how i will implement it. Obviously i need the function to be **GLOBAL** else i'll have to declare it to all functions to my controllers. That will only make my code longer and hard to follow.

I'll simply make a database table named as notification. With an essential column as status with only 2 possible variable as 'seen' 'unseen'. Since i have a user that has two roles(author and reader) for author any new review submitted to the story posted and for reader any new chapter added to bookshelved/bookmarked story.

Anyhow, i want to make a global function to parse the table for all updates to the user logged in(recent 5) and print them inside a dropdown on my navbar and just set in html a php if statement whether it is unseen or not and if it is highlight it.(rough idea, adjusted later during implementation)

My problem is that the first way i thought of to implement this was to make use of a constructor or index function to my controllers and store the data in a global `$data = array('notification' => array());` variable.

Then i searched google and found another way and that was to use base_controller. I also havent implemented checks in my controller if a user is logged in or not. I can do this in a constructor along with the notification but i also can do this with the base controller right?

anyway i would like to ask if which of the two is better(im leaning more on the 2nd but i could be wrong) and/or if there is a better method?

Comment: I think you can create helper put notification function there and now you can call this function in controller

Comment: I know that but compared to the ones above i think making a separate helper is just complicated? not in a complex way but in a way that is roundabout? anyways, i think making a library for it is better than making a helper. Every other CI_plugin i saw were always made into a library. Idk i just feel like that's not its intended use? then again i like php/ci for its flexibility of use so i guess theres no wrong way but its more of whats more acceptable.

Comment: you just create helper and autoload it so you can direct call any function anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `global` in CodeIgniter. For example, if you wanted to get a notification you could simply make a model called `notification_model` and autoload it. Then, in *any* controller `$this->notification_model->get_notifications()` will be available, for example. OR in `notification_model` class constructor you could do:

```
public $data = array();

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->data = $this->get_notifications();
}
```

and similarly to `$this->notification_model->get_notifications()`, `$this->notifications_model->data` will be available globally.

---

Now in terms of `base_controller` (really should be called `MY_Controller`) you are indeed correct in thinking that extending a modified `CI_Controller` for all your controllers that require authorization is a good idea.

This article adequately addresses this kind of scheme: https://codeinphp.github.io/post/controllers-for-frontend-and-backend-in-codeigniter/

I tend to shy away from putting Auth code in my `MY_Controller` and instead opt for a function like `$this->auth_util->protect(array('user', 'editor'));` (redirects to login if not logged in, shows 403 if user group not permitted to access function) in each function call at the top especially when dealing with functions that only pertain to certain user groups. One could handle this by detected the `uri_segment` in the `MY_Controller`, but then you would need a hardcoded list of `controller/function`s and group permissions so I prefer my approach.

With that being said, anything defined in your `MY_Controller` and assigned to a public property is also *globally* available.

```
// /application/core/MY_Controller.php
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public $notifications;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        if ($this->is_logged_in()) {
            $this->get_notifications();
        } else {
            redirect('/login');
        }
    }

    public function is_logged_in() {
        return $this->session->has_userdata('user_id');
    }

    public function get_notifications() {
        $q = $this->db->get(...);
        $this->notifications = $q->result();
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
class Some_controller extends MY_Controller {

    public function index() {
        print_r($this->notifications);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'll just use the My_controller method then. Also is it a better idea to just use an existing CI_Plugin for authentications rather than making my own?

Comment: Yes! So glad you asked. So many people try and reinvent the wheel. I personally use Ion Auth. It is very easy to setup user groups.

Comment: When installing the ion auth plugin, it says on the installation guide to run the appropriate sql file but idk which one is the appropriate since there are 3 sql files inside the sql directory but i'll just assume its the one named ion_auth.sql?

Comment: Yea, the others are for postgre or mssql I think

Comment: Is there any important info i should keep in mind using ion auth?

Comment: https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/issues/979 read my bottom comment. that's the only thing to be aware of in my experience

Comment: Would it pose a problem for me? i'm only making a project not actually uploading it to the web. I just wanted to relearn since i stopped 3-4 years ago and that was when i was learning php with codeigniter.

Comment: not really. and generally if its just local you can keep caching off. so don't worry about it. good luck!

Comment: Btw, How do i use the redirect function if i separated my view into portions like above? I have my header/navbar/footer inside a template folder.

Comment: Your views have nothing to do with the redirect function. The redirect function only goes to controllers e.g. `/somecontroller/somemethod/`